# GetPrivateprofilestring does not get an ini file in current directory

Tags: c++, winapi

Well, the title say which is my problem

my .cpp code is:

```
GetPrivateProfileString("Server","MainDns","ServerDns",
    g_DataBaseDns,sizeof(g_DataBaseDns),".\\Server.ini");
```

when I use:

```
GetPrivateProfileString("Server","MainDns","ServerDns",
    g_DataBaseDns,sizeof(g_DataBaseDns),"..\\Server.ini");
```

and Put the ini file in the back folder: works normally!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try without the single dot notation? (that is: "Server.ini")

Comment: Yes! Not successful :/

Comment: It is quite a horrid function and should not be used anymore.  Documentation for the last argument says: "If this parameter does not contain a full path to the file, the system searches for the file in the Windows directory."

Comment: Really?
So which function could I use?

Comment: From [GetPrivateProfileString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353.aspx): *"Applications should store initialization information in the registry."* If you want to continue to use `GetPrivateProfileString` you should at least be using fully qualified paths.

Comment: And if you want to use ini files then use a proper library

Answer (score 1):

You need to first call [`GetFullPathName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963.aspx) to obtain an absolute path, which is required according to the documentation for [`GetPrivateProfileString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353.aspx):

> The name of the initialization file. **If this parameter does not contain a full path to the file, the system searches for the file in the Windows directory**.

For example:

```
TCHAR sAbsolutePathBuffer[2048] = _T("");
if (GetFullPathName(TEXT("Server.ini"), sizeof(sAbsolutePathBuffer)/sizeof(TCHAR), sAbsolutePathBuffer, NULL))
{
    GetPrivateProfileString(TEXT("Server"), TEXT("MainDns"), TEXT("ServerDns"),
        g_DataBaseDns, sizeof(g_DataBaseDns), sAbsolutePathBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Note that `GetFullPathName()` converts a relative path to an absolute path using the calling process's current working directory, NOT the directory that the process executable is run from. The `GetFullPathName()` documentation warns about this. To create an absolute path that is relative to the executable's path, consider using `GetModuleFileName(NULL)`, `Path(Cch)RemoveFileSpec()`, and `Path(Cch)Combine()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It works now, under Visual Studio 2019, c++20.

Now, you can use `".\\"` or `"./"` as current path.